# Iterate R function over levels of a factor

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I am working on a function where I am adjusting exposed surface areas of some geometric shapes based on how these are pieced together. In the actual application, I am often dealing with missing data for some shapes, so I will need to deal with that in the function.

I want to iterate the same type of adjustment for each subject ("ind") in the data set.

```
testdata <- 
  data.frame(ind = rep(paste(letters[1:10]), each =2), A = rnorm(20, mean = 10, sd = 3), shape = rep(c("sphere", "ellipsoid"), 10), 
             x = rnorm(10, mean = 5, sd = 1))


funct <- function(A, shape, x, subject) {
  #Create NA aware function to deal with missing factor levels
  sum_ <- function(...) sum(..., na.rm=T) 

  radius <- x / 2

   A <- dplyr::case_when(
    shape %in% "sphere" ~ A - sum_((pi * radius[which(shape %in% 'cylinder')]^2)), 
    shape %in% "cylinder" ~ A -  sum_(2*(pi * radius^2)), 
    shape %in% "ellipsoid" ~ A -  sum_((0.2 * A[which(shape %in% "sphere")]), (2 * pi * radius[which(shape == "cylinder")]))
  )
  return(A)
}
```

This function produces the expected output, *but only when I do very simple adjustments such as adding or subtracting*. When I actually go ahead with the code above, the result is way off.

So I tried adding a loop to the function, without luck:

```
funct <- function(A, shape, x, subject) {
  #Create NA aware function to deal with missing factor levels
  sum_ <- function(...) sum(..., na.rm=T) 

  radius <- x / 2

  for(levels in levels(subject)) {
   A <- dplyr::case_when(
    shape %in% "sphere" ~ A - sum_((pi * radius[which(shape %in% 'cylinder')]^2)), 
    shape %in% "cylinder" ~ A -  sum_(2*(pi * radius^2)), 
    shape %in% "ellipsoid" ~ A -  sum_((0.2 * A[which(shape %in% "sphere")]), (2 * pi * radius[which(shape == "cylinder")]))
  )
  }
  return(A)
}
```

This is what I am getting:

```
testdata$result <- funct(A = testdata$A, shape = testdata$shape, x = testdata$x, subject = testdata$ind)
```

And this is what I want:

```
testdata <- 
  testdata %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  mutate(expected = case_when(
    shape %in% "sphere" ~ A - sum_((pi * radius[which(shape %in% 'cylinder')]^2)), 
    shape %in% "cylinder" ~ A -  sum_(2*(pi * radius^2)), 
    shape %in% "ellipsoid" ~ A -  sum_((0.2 * A[which(shape %in% "sphere")]), (2 * pi * radius[which(shape == "cylinder")]))
    )
  )
```

Any suggestions for how to get this right?

Answer (score 1):

Consider `by` which is a base *R function* that does exactly as you need: *iterate over levels of a factor*. However, `by` passes subsetted `data.frame` into a defined method and returns a `list` of function's output.

Therefore, adjust parameters to only receive a data frame and then qualify all columns with data frame. And then `unlist` results to map cleanly into a new column:

```
funct <- function(df) {
  #Create NA aware function to deal with missing factor levels
  sum_ <- function(...) sum(..., na.rm=T)
  radius <- df$x / 2

  A <- dplyr::case_when(
    df$shape %in% "sphere" ~ df$A - sum_((pi * radius[which(df$shape %in% 'cylinder')]^2)), 
    df$shape %in% "cylinder" ~ df$A -  sum_(2*(pi * radius^2)), 
    df$shape %in% "ellipsoid" ~ df$A -  sum_((0.2 * df$A[which(df$shape %in% "sphere")]), 
                                             (2 * pi * radius[which(df$shape == "cylinder")]))
  )
  return(A)
}

testdata$A_new <- unlist(by(testdata, testdata$ind, funct))
```

**Output**

```
testdata 
#    ind         A     shape        x               A_new
# 1    a 10.762472    sphere 5.378723 10.762472, 7.641209
# 2    a  9.793703 ellipsoid 5.673754  9.268827, 9.077957
# 3    b  9.268827    sphere 5.274687  3.697459, 9.954235
# 4    b 10.931723 ellipsoid 5.870127  5.136058, 7.315795
# 5    c  3.697459    sphere 4.045259 15.532064, 6.427971
# 6    c 10.693726 ellipsoid 4.536622 11.287207, 5.004321
# 7    d  5.136058    sphere 4.558130  10.31248, 11.41084
# 8    d  8.343007 ellipsoid 4.486902  8.015844, 3.818175
# 9    e 15.532064    sphere 4.044176 12.234275, 2.507726
# 10   e  9.534384 ellipsoid 6.179843  4.168281, 4.036249
# 11   f 11.287207    sphere 5.378723 10.762472, 7.641209
# 12   f  7.261763 ellipsoid 5.673754  9.268827, 9.077957
# 13   g 10.312481    sphere 5.274687  3.697459, 9.954235
# 14   g 13.473335 ellipsoid 5.870127  5.136058, 7.315795
# 15   h  8.015844    sphere 4.045259 15.532064, 6.427971
# 16   h  5.421344 ellipsoid 4.536622 11.287207, 5.004321
# 17   i 12.234275    sphere 4.558130  10.31248, 11.41084
# 18   i  4.954581 ellipsoid 4.486902  8.015844, 3.818175
# 19   j  4.168281    sphere 4.044176 12.234275, 2.507726
# 20   j  4.869905 ellipsoid 6.179843  4.168281, 4.036249
```

*By* the way, you can run full base R with nested `ifelse` within your function:

```
  val1 <- df$A - sum_((pi * radius[which(df$shape %in% 'cylinder')]^2))
  val2 <- df$A - sum_(2*(pi * radius^2))
  val3 <- df$A - sum_((0.2 * df$A[which(df$shape %in% "sphere")]),
                      (2 * pi * radius[which(df$shape == "cylinder")]))

  A <- ifelse(df$shape %in% "sphere", val1, 
              ifelse(df$shape %in% "cylinder", val2, 
                     ifelse(df$shape %in% "ellipsoid", val3, NA)
              )
       )
```

Comment: Thanks - I will consider these notes!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap a function around the code that works?

```
funct <- function(DF){
  stopifnot(require('dplyr'))
  DF %>%
    mutate(radius = x/2) %>%
    group_by(ind) %>%
    mutate(expected = case_when(
      shape %in% "sphere" ~ A - sum_((pi * radius[which(shape %in% 'cylinder')]^2)), 
      shape %in% "cylinder" ~ A -  sum_(2*(pi * radius^2)), 
      shape %in% "ellipsoid" ~ A -  sum_((0.2 * A[which(shape %in% "sphere")]), (2 * pi * radius[which(shape == "cylinder")]))
    )
    ) %>%
    pull(expected)
}
funct(testdata)
# [1]  6.3788028  9.5565272 13.2533235  0.3122422 11.2873741  9.2606929
# [7]  8.2757801  6.7049484  8.3066440  5.6685577  8.5684219  5.2911563
#[13]  7.6712383  8.6591288 12.8784822  7.0934471  8.4669715  5.5730195
#[19]  7.4884850 15.7498085
```

Or, to return the dataframe with a new column `expected`, replace the last pipe code line `pull(expected)` by `select(-radius)`. Then assign directly

```
testdata <- funct(testdata)
```

Comment: Thanks Rui - this is quite helpful!